# Suppressing hyphenation across pages

Tags: page-breaking, hyphenation

Is there a way of preventing the last word of a page from being hyphenated?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The penalty `\brokenpenalty` tells TeX how bad it is to break a page at a hyphen. You can absolutely forbid a break by doing

```
\brokenpenalty10000\relax
```

but then of course there will be a knock-on somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is that it is too late to consider the word as being non-hyphenable since the line-breaking algorithm is done already, and so the only possibility for TeX to avoid the break is to send that line to the next page or to load an additional line from it. If you have vertical flexibility then it may be ok, if your baselineskip and parskip are rigid, then it is not a good solution, you should better deal with it manually.