# How to prevent page breaks inside words?

Tags: page-breaking, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppressing hyphenation across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/suppressing-hyphenation-across-pages)

I would like to prevent page breaking from happening inside a word. In other words, hyphenation should not take place between pages. (This is what my publisher demands.) Is there a way to achieve this globally by setting some kind of penalties, or do I have to go through every page and remove the hyphens manually?