# How to avoid hyphenating a word on page break

Tags: page-breaking, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppressing hyphenation across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/suppressing-hyphenation-across-pages)

I'm writing a paper and it is bad style to hyphenate over page break. Is there a way to tell LaTeX not to hyphenate if it is the last word on a page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: See: [Suppressing hyphenation across pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/suppressing-hyphenation-across-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\mbox{do not break}` for example -- but do not put to much in it because if I recall correctly, then the spacing between the words will nor be good.

Comment: This deals with a completely different problem.

Comment: @egreg: Ok - maybe I understood the question wrong. Should I delete the answer?