# Stop Hyphenating Across Page Breaks

Tags: page-breaking, context, hyphenation

How to prevent hyphenation across page breaks?

Here is my minexample:

```
\starttext
\dorecurse{200}{Aprikosengeschmacksrichtung }
\stoptext
```

What I mean is a feature, which many other typographic programms have, e.g. Adobe Indesign, see here: http://indesignsecrets.com/stop-hyphenating-across-columns-and-page-breaks.php

Hyphenation across pages is really ugly and uncomfortable to read, how would you prevent them?

Comment: This is not a `context` solution, but you may get some ideas from the `impnattypo` package, which implements this rule of French typography for `LaTeX`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/french-typography-recommendations

Comment: See perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8558

Comment: No this \brokenpenalty does not work! It is without effect. See my minexample.

Comment: Is the ignore of \brokenpenalty simply a bug, or does ConTeXt servers another mechanism for the same effect?

Comment: Mustafa, my friend, effects are easy. Look closely `\dorecurse{200}{Aprikosenge\/schmacksrichtung}`

Comment: adding the following can prevent hyphenation I'm not sure if it is good practice though `\pretolerance=10000`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: You cannot suppress hyphenation at a page break in the usual TeX formats (plain, latex, context). You can discourage a page break at a hyphenated line (\brokenpenalty does this).

Somewhat longer explanation: TeX breaks paragraphs into lines. The lines are than broken into pages without touching the line breaks again. So you can shift the page break around in the presence of hyphenated lines; but you cannot tell TeX to retry on breaking the paragraph into lines when the page break falls on a hyphen. Note that shifting the page break has other "costs": Unevenly distributed white space on the pages, maybe different page heights, or other side effects (figure placement).

I will not exclude that someone writes an advanced output routine to allow retrying the line breaking, but I am not aware that anyone has done this already.