# Hyphenation across pages: summary of odd pages with last hyphenated word

Tags: hyphenation

AFAIK, `LaTeX` first makes the paragraphs beautiful, and after that it makes the pages beautiful. Thus if by any chance the pagebreak happens inside a hyphenated word, `LaTeX` can change the pagebreaks (if `\brokenpenalty` [is really big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/suppressing-hyphenation-across-pages) or package `impnattypo` is used) and put one or more lines on the next page. But `LaTeX` will not rebuild the paragraph once again to make it look different.

In addition, the hyphenated last word on an even page is not as ugly as the one on an odd page (you don't have to turn the page).

And the question is: is it possible to make `LaTeX` (or even some other program) issue warnings or write info to some external file with the information about the odd pages that end up with a hyphenated word?

Comment: I think the `fwlw` package can be helpfull http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fwlw/fwlw.pdf

Comment: May be relevant based on abstract: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-3/tb68fine.pdf

Comment: An idea: If I don't have footnotes, I might use `pdftotext -bbox` and look for `-</word></page>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might be as follows.

First we export our pdf into txt with all information about coordinates:

```
pdftotext -bbox myTeX.pdf myTeX.txt
```

Then we write a `Perl` program to find the words that end up with hyphen, and after that word either the page breaks, or the next word is not so close (not on the next line — we have some separation from footnotes and the footer). This is defined by `$minDelta` (in points). And, as stated in the question, we perform this check only for odd pages.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Tell me the filename\n";
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

my $page=0;
my $page_pattern='<page width=\"[0-9.]*\" height=\"[0-9.]*\">';
my $hyph_pattern='-</word>';
my $word_pattern='<word';
my $split_pattern="\"|<|>";
my $minDelta = 15;
my $delta=0;
while (my $line = <$data>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ "$page_pattern") { $page++; }
  if ($page % 2 == 1)
  {
        if ($line =~ "$hyph_pattern")
        {
             my @fields = split $split_pattern, $line;
             my $yMax = $fields[8];
             my $word = $fields[10];
             $line = <$data>;
             chomp $line;
             if ($line =~ "$word_pattern")
             {
                   @fields = split $split_pattern, $line;
                   $delta = abs($fields[8]-$yMax);
                   if ( $delta > $minDelta)
                   { print "page: $page, word: «$word», delta=$delta\n"; }
            }
            else  { print "page: $page, word: «$word», delta=$delta\n"; }
             if ($line =~ "$page_pattern")  {$page++; print "page: $page\n";}
        }
  }
}
print "done\n";
```

This might have some bugs with files containing `<` in the text, but in simpler cases this should work.